# What is the product of the maxterm and "dont't care" max term of an output in digital system?

Tags: karnaugh-map

"Use a K-map to simplyfy (all possible cases)"

```
F(A,B,C,D) = ∏(1,5,6,7,9,11,15)⋅D(5,7,10,12)
```

Specifically, at outputs 5 and 7, how should I interpret them in the Karnaugh map?

I searched up information about this specific problem yet found nothing

Answer (score 1):

Maxterm `5` can be translated to the expression

```
!A or B or !C or D
```

Inverting all inputs yields value `0` for `A and !B and C and !D`

Similarly, maxterm `7` is expressed as

```
!A or B or C or D
```

This results in value `0` for `A and !B and !C and !D`

Your example is described by the following truth table:

```
A B C D | P   DC   F
--------+---+----+---
0 0 0 0 | 0 |    | 0
0 0 0 1 | 1 |    | 1
0 0 1 0 | 1 |    | 1
0 0 1 1 | 1 |    | 1
0 1 0 0 | 0 |    | 0
0 1 0 1 | 1 | X  | X
0 1 1 0 | 0 |    | 0
0 1 1 1 | 1 | X  | X
1 0 0 0 | 0 |    | 0    inverse of maxterm 7
1 0 0 1 | 0 |    | 0
1 0 1 0 | 0 | X  | 0    inverse of maxterm 5
1 0 1 1 | 1 |    | 1
1 1 0 0 | 1 | X  | X
1 1 0 1 | 1 |    | 1
1 1 1 0 | 0 |    | 0
1 1 1 1 | 1 |    | 1
--------+---+----+---
```

A don't care condition turns `1` into `X`.
`0` remains `0`, because an `AND` results in `0` if at least one input is `0`.

Depicted as a [Karnaugh-Veitch map](https://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/%7Ethormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/):
[image]

Comment: I don't understand why 12 |-> X but 10 |-> 0. I've never seen this ∏ and D notation, which might be the reason of confusion. ∏ := product of maxterms? D := X if in the list 1 otherwise??

Comment: Isn't maxterm at ```5``` means the output at combination #5 will be 0? The same goes for output #7